# Long Batch script messes up "cd.."?

Tags: batch-file, cd, parse-error

I have a Batch file approx. 35 KB, ~1500-1800 lines. After the 500-line mark, all CD commands are parsed twice. So:

```
cd ..
```

would be seen as

```
cd ..
cd ..
```

For some reason, nothing I do changes this. Can ANYONE help? I'm running WIN10, 64-bit.

Comment: There's no reason for that to happen. I'd have to see the entire script. Link to pastebin or something.

Comment: Are you changing the bat file while it runs?

Comment: Add some outputs to see what really happens, like `echo #1 <newline> cd ..  <newline> echo #2`

Comment: @SomethingDark I cannot, as it could be stolen or leaked.

Comment: @bgalea No. I'm not stupid.

Comment: @jeb it outputs junk at an amazing rate.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why that would be happening, but I'd just try to work around it.  I would suggest splitting up your batch program into smaller chunks, if you can.  Create a 'main' batch program that `CALL`s your smaller routines.  This might also make your massive monolithic program a bit more manageable, too.